# React-virtualized Cellmeasurer defaulting to 'minHeight' of the CellMeasurerCache

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I'm using a react-virtualized List component, which uses height data from `CellMeasurerCache`:

`const cache = new CellMeasurerCache({fixedWidth: true, rowHeight: 150, minHeight: 50 });`

This is the code for the list:

```
return (
  <div className={classes.maxHeight}>
    <AutoSizer>
      {({height, width}) =>
        <List
          className='List'
          height={height}
          width={width}
          overscanRowCount={5}
          rowCount={content.length}
          rowHeight={cache.rowHeight}
          rowRenderer={listRowRenderer(content)}>
        </List>
      }
    </AutoSizer>
  </div>);
```

The problem is that, sometimes the height is defaulting to `minHeight`, and i want it to use the actual computed height

[See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWHZn.png) , the two cards have a default height of 50, when they should have a computed height based on their content. If I scroll down and back up, they will be computed properly, so should this be forced somehow or...?

The `listRowRenderer`:

```
const item = data[index];

return (
  <CellMeasurer
    cache={cache}
    columnIndex={0}
    key={key}
    rowIndex={index}
    parent={parent}>
    {({measure, registerChild}) =>
      <div ref={registerChild} style={style}>
        (content here)
      </div>
    }
  </CellMeasurer>
);
```

I even tried using the `measure` from `CellMeasurer` inside `useEffect` of the card component

Comment: I also tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/47188992/17299932 , give each individual item it's own measure function, but that didn't work either

Comment: UPDATE: The height is actually fine, it's just that they are positioned way too close to eachother

Comment: UPDATE2: Found the problem. The components need to be re-rendered, somehow. Calling measure() IS the solution, but i can't find a proper place to call the measure function to make it work. Putting it in useEffect will NOT work, but if i put it behind a sleep, it WILL work, which is obviously not a solution but at least i now know that the measure function will fix things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's not okay to use 1 cache in multiple locations. I had an UI with 3 tabs, each tab loading virtualized data, and each tab used the same cache which messed things up. I gave each tab it's individual cache and voila it worked.